# Remove time from a range of dates in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I need all the values of the DataFrame to not have a time element.
For example with the dataframe:

```
df = pd.date_range("2019-01-01'", periods = 9, freq='M')
```

Currently `df[2]` shows:

`2019-03-31 00:00:00`

What is the best way to remove the time part and just include the date for all elements in the array?

Comment: `pd.date_range("2019-01-01", periods = 9, freq='M').date`

Comment: That was quick, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome and good luck.